# Styling links with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm styling my `<a>`'s with jQuery UI. I did this:

```
$( "button, input:submit, a#jql" ).button();
```

My input:submit looks beautiful, but that's because I have no actual styling for such an element, so it uses purely the jQuery UI CSS. However, my `<a>`'s have a huge amount of styling, but I want to create unstyled links so that my current styling doesn't interfere whatsoever with jQuery UI styling. Should I just turn them into buttons? I have those unstyled too.

The jQuery UI has different rules for `<a>` links and for input:submits (the latter is shorter in height). I just need them to have the same styling, but I can't change the links to submits. Could anyone familiar with this point me in the direction I want?

Comment: I didn't know you could use this for css. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of pre-existing CSS on `<a>` tags then the easiest thing would be to make the ones you want to be controlled by jQuery UI into a `<button>`.  Another option would be to put a CSS class on the `<a>` tags that you want to be controlled by the jQuery UI button and then reset all of the CSS for that CSS class, but that feels heavy handed.  The reset would need to undo all of the styles you already have set on `<a>` tags.

Comment: jQuery styles anchor links and buttons in the same way. The submit button is the only one that looks different. Without digging into jQuery UI, is there a way to make them all styled the same?

Comment: Hm the submit button looks the same as the links and buttons in this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/).  Perhaps you have some CSS on the page for input submits that is affecting it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own `<a>` styling. Just declare it in your CSS file and set it to important. The same goes for any other UI classes, Just do the re-declare in your CSS and set to important, so yours will have the priority.

Ex:

```
a{
 color:red !important;
 padding:5px !important;
 ...
}
```

Below are 2 great links on how to use the jQuery UI CSS framework.

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137970/jQuery-UI-CSS-Framework

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Comment: @Sennheiser if this answers your questions, don't forget to check the answer.